# Autohotkey Arrow Key stuck / blocked to infinity after a Send

Tags: autohotkey

When I Send a {Down Down} key : Bottom Arrow, the key stay stuck to infinity. I would like to just push it once with this code :

```
F8::
Send {Down Down}
return
```

I've tried with Sleep and a tons of other solutions but it was not a success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first down in your code implies you want to hold the key "Down".
"Down" and "Up" are prefixes to key state.

```
F8::
Send {Down}
return
```